# Ошибка “PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in…” exlode

Tags: php

Прочитал много тем по этой ошибке, но как поправить у себя, так и не понял.

```
foreach($data as $date => $stat):
    $from = htmlspecialchars(trim(explode(" - ",$date)[0]));
    $to = (trim(explode(" - ",$date)[1])=='') ? $from : htmlspecialchars(trim(explode(" - ",$date)[0]));
    $html .= "<tr><td colspan='6'><hr></td></tr>\r\n";
```

ошибка в строке 207

```
$to = (trim(explode(" - ",$date)[1])=='') ? $from : htmlspecialchars(trim(explode(" - ",$date)[0]));
```

Comment: `1` у вас вроде только здесь: `explode(" - ",$date)[1]`, значит смотрите что находится в `$date` и почему `explode(" - ",$date)` возвращает не то, что надо

Comment: Выводите на экран ключи $date до строки 207 для проверки.

Comment: скорее всего пробелы вокруг тире не нужны, и у вас в коде косяк, а все потому, что одним выражением пытаетесь сразу кучу операций совершить. В 207 строке последняя часть разве `[0]` должна быть? Тогда почему `$from` сразу не использовать? Они же равны между собой

Comment: извиняюсь, [0] сюда попал уже после эсперементов, конечно [1].

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем. Поправил код так:

```
foreach($data as $date => $stat):
    if(isset($date[1])){
        $to = htmlspecialchars(trim(explode(" - ",$date)[0]));
        $from = htmlspecialchars(trim(explode(" - ",$date)[0]));
    }else{
        $to = htmlspecialchars(trim(explode(" - ",$date)[1]));
    }
}
```

В первом коде, я использовал несуществующую переменную `$date[1]`.

Comment: Условие в этом коде похоже на бред ;)